# is it possible to put the template of a component in an other folder then the template folder in Symfony

Tags: php, templates, symfony1, components

I have a component that calls a template from the template folder as it should be done. But as there are a lot of files in the template folder i would rather have them split up in different sub folders.
Is it possible to call a template in a specific folder for a component? And how is this done?

now i have public function executeTest(){} that automatically calls the template _Test.php in the template folder.

Is it possible and somehow create a subfolder in the template folder where this _Test.php file is located? Can you put some code in the executeTest(){} to get a template from that subfolder

thx in advance.

This is all to improve the overview of files and increase readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I've been thinking of and wanting to do since I started using Symfony over a year ago. As far as I know, there is no simple way of doing this. I usually end up creating new modules or using some kind of naming scheme that makes the partials easier to find.